# Firebase Reactjs get current user from context

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm new of Reactjs and I'd like to understand if the only way to get Firebase `currentUser` from context is through `onAuthStateChanged`.

I try to be more clear: let's say I signed-in by a "SignIn" component by using Firebase context and, after signed-in, I need to get `currentUser` in a different component, it seems to me the only way to get it is something like:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

...

 useEffect(() => {
    props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      if (!!authUser) {
        setUser(authUser);
      } 
    }); 
  }, []);
```

Is it true?

Thanks

Comment: you can use redux to store authUser and than can use that information through out your app using props .

Answer (score 2):

## You can call on a current user any time

You can use this auth function

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

You don't have to store it. Unless you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to who reply my question, I found the answer in [this detailed article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial).